# Can a column be restricted to taking one or another foreign key as an entry?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, alter-table

I have been attempting to constrain a column to accept an entry which can only be foreign key A entry **OR** foreign key B entry but I am not sure if this is possible?

For context I am creating a helpdesk database with a table called ticket which contains a "resolved_by" column which I want to only accept the values of either  "analyst_id" or a "specialist_id" each of these values is a primary key for the table "analyst" and "specialist" respectively.

I have added separate constraints  to the column specifying each key as the only input accepted but am getting an error "integrity constraint (S21005182.SYS_C00234833) violated - parent key not found" when trying to add a new record to the table.

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET(
    Id_Caller               CHAR(6)       REFERENCES Caller (Id_Caller),
    Id_Ticket               CHAR(6)       PRIMARY KEY,
    Problem_Description     VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
    Id_General_Problem      CHAR(6)       REFERENCES General_Problem_Types(Id_General_Problem),
    Id_Specific_Problem     CHAR(6)       REFERENCES Specific_Problem_Types(Id_Specific_Problem),
    OPENDED_DATE_TIME       DATE          DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
    Opened_By               CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
    Assigned_To             CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
    RESOLVED_By             CHAR(6),
    RESOLVED_DATE_TIME      DATE,
    TIME_TAKEN_TO_RESOLVE   NUMBER(5,0),
    RESOLUTION_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(500)
);

ALTER TABLE TICKET 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (resolved_by) REFERENCES Specialist (ID_SPEACIALIST);

ALTER TABLE TICKET 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (resolved_by) REFERENCES Analyst (Id_Analyst);

INSERT INTO ticket
VALUES(0, ticket_IDS.nextval, 'Cracked Screen', 500020, 600000,'11-MAY-2020' ,100000, 200000, 200000, '19-MAY-2020',90,'replaced screen' );
```

I believe this means that the entry is being denied as one of the foreign keys isn't present in the entry (but the other one is) ie the entry is a foreign key b value but not foreign key A.

So currently my code is denying entries that aren't both foreign key B and foreign key A?

Comment: Foreign keys only can be used to garanty that the values exist in the other table, for comex behaviour Zou can use trigger

Comment: It is a little bit strange you would create separate `analyst` and `specialist` tables. Would it not be more simple to have 1 table containing everyone with a `role` column and/or an `analyst`/`specialist` table to join to it?

Comment: If you have one column that needs to link to two different tables then you probably want to review your data model design - as that does not appear to be a design that meets common modelling standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you should consolidate `SPECIALIST` and `ANALYST` into a single table and use a type column to distinguish between them. Then you have a single PK constraint that your `TICKET` foreign key can reference.

If there is a considerable amount of attribute divergence between them such that keeping them as separate attributes makes sense, then you need a supertype-subtype relation, wherein a common entity (`PERSON`) covers the shared attributes of two subtypes, `SPECIALIST` and `ANALYST`. You would then model it:

```
TICKET -> PERSON <- ANALYST
                 <- SPECIALIST
```

In this model `PERSON` would master the `PERSON_ID` primary key, have a type indicator specifying which subtype it belongs to (to know what subtype table to join to), and have any other attributes common to both analysts and specialists, whereas `ANALYST` and `SPECIALIST` would each of the `PERSON_ID` key (both as a PK *and* an FK to `PERSON` in order to enforce a 1:1 relationship) and any attributes that are specific to the subtype. Once again, you can have your TICKET foreign key reference PERSON, a single supertype entity.

Lastly, if there's any chance your ticket can be resolved by two people, one analyst and one specialist, then you need two separate columns in your `TICKET` table and separate FKs on each. But, if it can be resolved by more than two or by two people of the same role, or your roles can potentially morph in the future, then you are best off with a many-to-many bridge table `TICKET_RESOLVERS` so you can associate as many resolvers as you need. That bridge table in any case would point to the consolidated or supertype `PERSON`.